# View with geospatial and non geospatial keys with CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, spatial-query

I'm using CouchDB and GeoCouch and I'm trying to understand if it were possible to build a geospatial index and "query" the database both by using a location and a value from another field.

**Data**

```
{
   "_id": "1",
   "profession": "medic",
   "location": [15.12, 30.22]
}

{
   "_id": "2",
   "profession": "secretary",
   "location": [15.12, 30.22]
}

{
   "_id": "3",
   "profession": "clown",
   "location": [27.12, 2.2]
}
```

**Questions**

Is there any way to perform the following queries on these documents:

- Find all documents with `job = "medic"` near location [15.12, 30.22] *(more important)*
- List all the different professions near this location [15.12, 30.22] *(a plus)*

In case that's not possible, what options do I have? I'm already considering switching to MongoDB, but I'd rather solve in a different way.

**Notes**

- Data changes quickly, new documents might be added and many might be removed

**References**

[Faceted search with geo-index using CouchDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101367/faceted-search-with-geo-index-using-couchdb?rq=1)

Comment: Have you considered using _list functions to handle filtering like this? I'm not experienced with Geocouch, so I can't speak any further on how to use it specifically.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes, but I'm not quite sure on how to use them with GeoCouch to solve my problem efficiently.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch/#list-function-support) out, it looks like you can create a view index that outputs all the documents you need. In your list function, you iterate as normal, but you only output the data you need. In a list function, you have access to querystring parameters, so you can use that data to determine your filtering method.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this could be an helpful workaround in case I don't find another solution! ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3638678/261698))

Comment: did you end up finding a solution you could share?

Comment: @ErikAllik, no. Unfortunately not.